# playframework: Reading body of WSResponse with a 400 status

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm calling a service which when returning a 400 response also includes some explanation on why the call failed in the body.

However Play's `WSResponse` seems to ignore the body unless it's a 200 status.

The version of Play I'm using (2.3.9) uses `com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponse`. If I dig in with a debugger I can find one `com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.ResponseBodyPart` and it's content field contains the body I'm expecting. But it appears to be already consumed (readerIndex = writerIndex = 125).

It does tell me there is a body (`hasResponseBody() == true`) and `getResponseBody` is returning a string, but an empty one.

Any ideas on how I can change that?

Comment: I'd recommend to add the tag 'playframework' to reach a wider audience.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Show us the code making the call